# Nearly close to go out of business vs. to going out of business

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, past-tense

What is the difference between these two:

> Suzuki was nearly close to **go** out of business just after the World War period.

Vs.

> Suzuki was nearly close to **going** out of business just after the World War period.(from a video)

When talking about the past, do these two sentences different from each other? Like, if you use **verbing**(going) with **infinitive**(to) in the **past**, does it mean that there is another event happening? Or none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct expression is “close to going” not “close to go”. “[To](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/close2_1)” is a preposition here and is followed by the “-ing” form.

Comment: Ths for the provided link. I just need to make sure if **close to doing** or the **ing** is only for verbs?

Comment: @JohnArvin - as you can see from the examples in the link, “close to” may be  followed by a verb (gerund) or a noun.

Comment: There's is no noun. And it says ''not to a noun''. I just want to be absolutely sure coz' I am still doubtful about some parts. Anyway, thx man.